# ios:how to set dynamic height for all iphone screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my application dn't use autolayout and size classes. Create all the elements programmatically.

Calculate view width and set frame for each element. Here my code.

```
UILabel* TitleLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-25,y,100, 50)];
    TitleLbl.text=@"Login";
    TitleLbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    TitleLbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
    [self.view addSubview:TitleLbl];
    y=y+30;

    UILabel* AccountLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-130,y,350, 50)];
    AccountLbl.text=@"Login or Create Your New Account";
    AccountLbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    AccountLbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
    [self.view addSubview:AccountLbl];
    y=y+40;



UIButton *LoginBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//    [LoginBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
//     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [LoginBtn setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    LoginBtn.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+40,y, self.view.frame.size.width-80, (self.view.frame.size.height/10));
    LoginBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    LoginBtn.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    LoginBtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    LoginBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    LoginBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    //LoginBtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
    [self.view addSubview:LoginBtn];


  UIButton *RegBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    //    [RegBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
    //     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [RegBtn setTitle:@"Register Now" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    RegBtn.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+40, y, self.view.frame.size.width-80, (self.view.frame.size.height/10));
    RegBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    RegBtn.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    RegBtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    RegBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    RegBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
    [self.view addSubview:RegBtn];
```

How can i calulate the dynamic heigth for this code. **especially**  UIButton *RegBtn,UIButton *LoginBtn these two button i cant able to put dynamic height.

Any one can help me. how to calulate dynamic heigth. give any solution for me. Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` to find the screen size and then dynamically change widths and heights of your UI elements accordingly. For example, you may want `RegBtn` to be 40 pixels smaller than the screen width. To do this you can simply calculate its width as `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.width – 40.0`

Comment: how to add for height.

Comment: @saravanaa `[UIscreen mainScreen].bounds.height`

Answer (score 0):

Take a `constant.h` class or already you have for code reusable purpose. Add this

```
#define SCREEN_SIZE ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size)
```

Then use `SCREEN_SIZE.height` & `SCREEN_SIZE.width` any where in your project irrespective of any screen size. (need to import the constant.h when you need in any VC). You can set any control's frame dynamically by calculating from `SCREEN_SIZE` like x, y coordinates or height, width.

I just tried your code and found Reg and Login buttons frame are same, so they are overlapping. I have fixed that, which could help you

```
UIButton *LoginBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//    [LoginBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
//     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[LoginBtn setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
LoginBtn.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+40,y, SCREEN_SIZE.width-80, (SCREEN_SIZE.height/10));
LoginBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
LoginBtn.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
LoginBtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
LoginBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
LoginBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
//LoginBtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
[self.view addSubview:LoginBtn];

y = CGRectGetHeight(LoginBtn.frame) + y + 16; // Need to update the y position

UIButton *RegBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//    [RegBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:)
//     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[RegBtn setTitle:@"Register Now" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
RegBtn.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+40, y, SCREEN_SIZE.width-80, (SCREEN_SIZE.height/10));
RegBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
RegBtn.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
RegBtn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
RegBtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
RegBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];
[self.view addSubview:RegBtn];
```

[image]

Happy coding ..

Answer (score 0):

I don't use auto layout and create everything programmatically, generally  I use something like this in the viewController:

```
@interface mainVC(){
 float w;
 float h;
}
-(void)viewDidLoad {
 w = self.view.frame.size.width;
 h = self.view.frame.size.height; 
}
-(void)layoutSomeElements {

 float yOff = 0;

 UIView * someView = [UIView new];
 someView.frame = CGrectMake(0,yOff,w,30);
 [self.view addSubview:someView];

 yOff += 30.0f;    

 UIView * anotherView = [UIView new];
 anotherView.frame = CGRectMake(0,yOff,w,50);
 [self.view addSubview:anotherView];

 yOff += 50.0f;

 UIView * bottomView = [UIView new];
 bottomView.frame = CGRectMake(0,h-50,w,50);
 [self.view bottomView];
}
```

It's neat and allows you to reshuffle your views around. You can use scaling, but it's better UI to keep your elements a constant size across devices and adapt using a scrollView etc.